# Poner un botón adentro de la cámara 

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Ya puse lo de cambiar de activity pero sin resultado... Esta en capture activity (cámara) el botón que asigne es back.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CaptureActivity Java:

```
@Override
protected void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.capture);

    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(CaptureActivity.this, calculatoractivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

Button xml (back)

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginVertical="320dip"
        android:background="@drawable/retrocesobtn"
        android:rotation="270"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:text="sig" />
```

Añadiendo una pregunta que va relacionada a la cámara, quiero quitar el menú de abajo que viene por default en los teléfonos: son los 3 botones de retroceso, del menú, y de pausa de la cámara, pero no sé cómo quitarlo.

No me aparece nada en el logcat.

Answer (score 1):

- Para poder efectuar el back desde una actividad. Puedes utilizar el método finish() de la activity que lo que hace ese cerrar la activity que se está mostrando. Basado en ello, puedes modificar tu código de la siguiente manera.

  ```
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish()
        }
    });
  ```

Con respecto a tu segunda pregunta. Esa barra en la parte de abajo de los teléfonos se llama Navigation Bar. Para ocultarlo puedes utilizar el siguiente código.

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
// SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
// a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
// hide the navigation bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Referencia: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation#java

Comment: Hola! ya lo intente lo de navigator bar pero sin resultado  (cheque lo de la pagina no me especifica en que parte del codigo java tiene que ir) y lo de boton de back andaba intentandolo pero tengo un problema con el protected void no lo puedo resolver lo unico que puedo hacer es remplazarlo en vez de onCreate poner "captureactivity" ¿Sugerencia? saludo2!